# invoking commands on Unix from Windows power shell

Tags: powershell

Is this possible ?, someone has suggested that I migth be able to do via ssh, essentially run a command on Unix pipe the output to a file get it back and then perform some action in the invoking Power Shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use tools like [`plink`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to execute a command via ssh on a remote server. Also you don't need to write the result to a file; you can simply assign it to a variable:

```
$output = plink ...
```

Comment: I've since found that a third party power shell extension called NetCmdlets allows you to do this: http://www.nsoftware.com/powershell/.

Answer (score 0):

With Win32-OpenSSH you can execute commands over SSH.  See [Win32-OpenSSH Examples](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/ssh.exe-examples).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible!
Have a look at [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/George-Ogden/UNIX) for all of the UNIX commands that have been compiled to run on Windows. Then, you can run both PowerShell and UNIX commands from PowerShell.